# RuntimeError: one of the variables needed for gradient computation has been modified by an inplace operation

Tags: python, pytorch, lstm, sequence, backpropagation

```
import torch

# Define the sequence of integers and the targets
sequences = [i for i in range(0, 9)]
targets = [i+1 for i in range(0, 9)]

# Convert the sequences and targets to tensors
sequences = torch.tensor(sequences, dtype=torch.float32)
targets = torch.tensor(targets, dtype=torch.float32)

class LSTM(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self, input_size, output_size):
    super(LSTM, self).__init__()
    self.lstm = nn.LSTM(input_size, 11)
    self.fc = nn.Linear(11, output_size)
    
    
  def forward(self, x,hidden):
    x,(h,c) = self.lstm(x,hidden)

    x = self.fc(x)
    return x,(h,c)

# Define the linear layer
model = LSTM(1, 11)

# Define the loss function and optimization algorithm
loss_fn = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.01,weight_decay=5e-4)

# Train the linear layer
for epoch in range(100):
  (h,c) = (torch.zeros(1, 11), torch.zeros(1, 11))
  # Forward pass
  for x,y in zip(sequences,targets): 
    x=x.unsqueeze(0).unsqueeze(0)
    outputs,(h,c) = model(x,(h,c))
    
    y=y.unsqueeze(0).type(torch.LongTensor)
    loss = loss_fn(outputs, y)
    

    # Backward pass
    loss.backward(retain_graph=True)


   # Update the weights
    optimizer.step()


   # Reset the gradient
    optimizer.zero_grad()
```

In this code we are passing the hidden `(h,c)` with every input. This code was written in *google colab*.

**output:**

```
RuntimeError: one of the variables needed for gradient computation has been
modified by an inplace operation: [torch.FloatTensor [11, 44]], which is output 0
of AsStridedBackward0, is at version 3; expected version 2 instead.
```